# golang appengine api testing error "appengine: NewContext passed an unknown http.Request"

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-app-engine-go

I'm using appengine and golang to develop simple RESTful APIs. The code works fine when I start service using goapp serve, and I started writing the unit test functions to test the API endpoints, and I'm struck here with the panic error `appengine: NewContext passed an unknown http.Request`. I'm getting this error when i run `goapp test`.

It looks like for some reason, i'm not able to pass the request that I created and pass it to `appengine.NewContext()`

Below is the snippet of the code..

```
body := strings.NewReader("")

request, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "endpoint url", body) //inst.NewRequest("GET", goalUrl, body) //
if err != nil {
    t.Error(err)
}
t.Log(request)

c := appengine.NewContext(request) // ERROR: appengine: NewContext passed an unknown http.Request
```

I have created a [simple reproducible code](https://github.com/muly/research/tree/APIUnitTestError22Simplified/golang/appengine/ApiTesting). Can you help me with this? or Does anyone have their golang API project on appengine, and have unit test functions to test the endpoints, i'll like to take a look at their code...

Here is the [gitlab issue](https://github.com/muly/lifelog/issues/22) that I posted, which has all the required details of the issue along with examples and detailed error message. Thank for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies for the delay in response. I was working on the solution myself

Here is how I solved the go appengine unit tests issue: the complete solution code can be found on [this github repo branch](https://github.com/muly/research/tree/APIUnitTestError22Solved/golang/appengine/ApiTesting).

In the *_test.go file, I have used the following.

- httptest.NewServer(..) to create a new instance of the test server. also used to capture the base url of the service which is used in preparing the request object.
- aetest.NewContext() to create a new context for testing purpose
- http.NewRequest(..) to create the new request
- gorilla's context.Set(..) to assign key ("Context"), value (context created in above step) to the request created above
- httptest.NewRecorder() a new recorder to save the results
- http.Handler.ServeHTTP(..) passing the recorded and request. used to make the API request

For each API handler code, instead of directly creating the new context using appengine.NewContext, I have code described in the below sudocode

```
using the gorilla's context.GetOk(..), check 
    IF the received request object has the key "Context"
    THEN using value of that key as the context
    ELSE derive context using appengine.NewContext(r)
```

I have wrapped the reusable functionality into a separate library called [aeunittest](https://github.com/muly/aeunittest) and used it in my code.

With this setup, i'm, able to run the goapp test to fire the unit tests. see the [solved code](https://github.com/muly/research/tree/APIUnitTestError22Solved/golang/appengine/ApiTesting) for complete details of the solution.

Here is the blogpost that helped me find this solution. Thanks a lot Mark. [TESTING GO HTTP HANDLERS IN GOOGLE APP ENGINE WITH MUX AND HIGHER ORDER FUNCTIONS](http://www.compoundtheory.com/testing-go-http-handlers-in-google-app-engine-with-mux-and-higher-order-functions/).

Answer (score 1):

`NewContext` derives a context from in [flight HTTP requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/reference#NewContext), i.e. ones that have been registered with it.

Since you are creating a new request, unknown to the [internal appengine package](https://github.com/golang/appengine/blob/master/internal/api.go#L254-L271), it's panicking.

That package also provides a [`RegisterTestRequest`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/appengine/internal#RegisterTestRequest) function, but it's not mentioned in the main documentation so YMMV. I have no experience with this.

Comment: thank you, but I see a note in the document saying "It should only be used by aetest package". I believe it might not be a risk. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Why do you need to call `NewContext` to begin with? Perhaps a better approach would be to completely separate the appengine specific parts of the logic, and make the application logic testable independent of appengine specific state?

Comment: the Context is required for the appengine datastore operations like put, get, so it is required in my case.

Comment: What I mean is that you could abstract those APIs into interfaces and provide a mock context and a mock datstore to boot (or just a datastore, if you can hide the context), compatible with but independent of the appengine package

Comment: i'm not sure how to do that. just now, I have posted a solution that I found working for me. I believe it is different than what you are talking about. However, I'm interested to learn your solution too.